# How to bind value and keydown event in same input element?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

When I binding an `Observable` variable to an `input` value, and `keydown` event as well, it's not updating the observable value

```js
function vModel() {
  var vm = this;
  
  vm.value = ko.observable();
  vm.keyDown = function() {
    
  };
}

ko.applyBindings(new vModel());
```

```html
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
  <input type="text" data-bind="value: value, event: {keydown: keyDown}">
  
  <span data-bind="text: value"></span>
```

How can I bind `value` and `event: {keydown: myKeyDown}` in same input element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return `true` in your event listener to make sure the key down makes it to the input.

*However*, you might want to look at the `textInput` binding (`textInput: value`) and subscribe to `value` instead...

```js
function vModel() {
  var vm = this;
  
  vm.value = ko.observable();
  vm.keyDown = function() {
    console.log("key down");
    return true;
  };
}

ko.applyBindings(new vModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<input type="text" data-bind="value: value, event: {keydown: keyDown}">    
<span data-bind="text: value"></span>
```

Comment: I got it, I will take a look at `textInput`, thank you so much!